# SequenceType implementation

Tags: swift

SequenceType in Swift implements _Sequence_Type but these two protocols seem basically the same.  Why is it implemented this way?

```
protocol SequenceType : _Sequence_Type {
    typealias Generator : GeneratorType
    func generate() -> Generator
}

protocol _SequenceType {
}

protocol _Sequence_Type : _SequenceType {

    /// A type whose instances can produce the elements of this
    /// sequence, in order.
    typealias Generator : GeneratorType

    /// Return a generator over the elements of this sequence.  The
    /// generator's next element is the first element of the sequence.
    func generate() -> Generator
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Protocols with leading underscores are Apple-private. The header for them typically does not include all of their actual methods. You can reverse engineer their actual methods by declaring a class to implement them, and see what the compiler says is missing. (The results are of course completely unsupported, and very likely to change between releases, which is why the particular protocol is likely private.)

In short, the answer is "because we don't actually know what's in those protocols."